# Using Euler totient function to show density of primes is 0.

Tags: proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory, totient-function

On [this](https://math.wikia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) site a proof that the density of primes is 0 is claimed. However, I am confused by multiple steps in this proof.

Firstly why does $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\phi(x)/x=0$ imply the density is 0? Is this because $\phi(p)+1=p$ or because primes are co-prime to most numbers? I'm not sure if those are valid explanations.

Secondly, is the taking of the limit justified? As $x\rightarrow\infty$ there will still be primes not dividing $x$, infinitely many in fact.

Finally are we justified in taking $\zeta(1)^{-1}=0$? Is this shown from taking the limit of the product?

The last two points I'm mostly ok with but I don't see how they derive the first implication and so will accept any answer which explains this.

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\phi(x)/x=0$ isn't true, though. There are still infinitely many primes, even though they do get sparser.

Comment: @Arthur Certainly it is true that the density of primes is 0 though? Given the PNT we can easily see that $\lim\pi(x)/x=\lim(x/\log(x))/x=\lim1/\log(x)=0$ as $\log$ is an increasing function.

Comment: @Arthur Also it's known at least that $\lim\inf\frac{\phi(x)\log\log{x}}{x}$ is constant so at the very least $\lim\inf\frac{\phi(x)}{x}=0$

Comment: $\liminf\frac{\phi(x)}{x}=0$ is even easily seen by restricting to the factorials. But the corresponding $\limsup$ is $1$ because there are infinitely many primes. So the actual limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @Arthur The observation that $\liminf$ is 0 on factorials is an interesting one but I can't seem to prove this. Could you outline an explanation for me?

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\phi(x)$ given the prime factorisation of $x$? From there, it isn't difficult to see that $\frac{\phi(x)}{x}$ is mostly a measure of how many distinct prime factors $x$ has. Factorials have more and more prime factors, and thus $\frac{\phi(n!)}{n!}$ goes to $0$. Primorials work even better.

Comment: In fact, $\limsup\varphi(x)/x=1$